# How would I send mySQL queries/ results from ExpressJS to react?

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, express

I'm creating a react program,which I want to connect to a mysql database I created on sql workbench. So far, I created the front end from react, the database from mySQL, and collected information on creating the express, connecting to the database from express, and connecting the react to express. What I need to know now: how would I send data from react to express?

I need to send
1: A query/data values in the query from react to express when trying to insert values to the data base

2: A query/data values in the query from react to express when trying to search for specific values in the data base

3: results of the query (number 2) from express to react, so I can display them on the program.

Havent tried any attempts yet, but this is my first time connecting to a DB from a frontend, so I want to plan before coding, but I struggled to find info on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: A react program does a HTTP request, Express responds with data.

Comment: It's a large question, in short on the frontend you will do the api request using for ex fetch or axios library, with http method like GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, then on the backend you build for ex a restful API, using CRUD operation to query your DB.